# PouchDB relative remote database (with CouchDB / Cloudant)

Tags: database, couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

I am creating a CouchApp and have a question about remote databases and creating a PouchDB object.

- The CouchApp is available from htps://subdomain.website.com/
- The CouchDB instance is on htps://username.cloudant.com/database
- I use a rewrite rule in the database
- There is a Virtual Host from subdomain.website.com to username.cloudant.com/database/_design/client/_rewrite
- I am not using replication, only a direct connection

I currently create a new PouchDB object using:

> var db = new PouchDB('htps://username.cloudant.com/database');

But I would rather instantiate it as:

> var db = new PouchDB('/database');

or

> var db = new PouchDB('database');

My guess is that PouchDB sees this as a local database instead of a remote database. Is my thinking correct, and how can I get my desired result? I want to strip the hostname of the URL because I want to keep everything portable and replicate it over other servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you defined a vhost, you can use the following workaround mabye :

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var host = url.host;

var db = new PouchDB(host+"/database");
```

Comment: Good out of the box thinking! This fixed my problem. I did add an extra rewrite rule to get the vhost rerouting working: `{
      "from": "/database/*",
      "to": "../../../database/*"
    }`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out)

I'm using `create-react-app` and wanted to use a `proxy` directive, so I could redirect all `pouchdb` requests to my `/couchdb1` endpoint and avoid all the CORS issues.

So here you go:

```js
const COUCHDB_ROOT = '/couchdb1';
const remoteDB = new PouchDB(COUCHDB_ROOT + '/userdb-626f62', {
  adapter: 'http',
  fetch: (url, opts) => {
    if (typeof url === 'string') {
      return PouchDB.fetch(COUCHDB_ROOT + url.split(COUCHDB_ROOT)[1], opts)
    } else {
      throw new Error('The url could be of a Request type.'); // TODO
    }
  },
  auth: {
    username: 'bob',
    password: 'bob',
  },
  skip_setup: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I currently create a new PouchDB object using:
>
> var db = new PouchDB('htps://username.cloudant.com/database');
>
> But I would rather instantiate it as:
>
> var db = new PouchDB('database');

Well, that's not a matter of personal preference, you might need a remote database, a local database, or both.

Basically, as the developer you might need a remote database:

```
const remoteDB=new PouchDB('https://username.cloudant.com/database')
```

Also, you might need a local database:

```
const localDB=new PouchDB('localDatabase')
```

Then, probably you might need to `sync` the remote and local databases. Actually, the `syncing` is what **PouchDB really shines** at. For example, syncing might be done like this:

```
localDB.sync(remoteDB,{live:true,retry:true}).on('complete',()=>{
    console.log('sync done')
}).on('change',change=>{
    console.log('Something changed -> ',change)
}).on('paused',info=>{
    console.log('Sync paused -> ',info)
}).on('active',info=>{
    console.log('Sync is active again -> ',info)
}).on('error',err=>{
    throw new Error(err)
})
```

You can [read on](https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html) for more info.

Comment: I am not using a local database nor replication as the dataset is rather large. The remote dataset is read-only and I instantiate PouchDB using a remote instance only. After that I use alldocs to query the database.